# MS OneDrive JavaScript SDK Handlers Not Global?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, onedrive

I am trying to implement the v7 OneDrive SDK found [here](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdk/js-v7/js-picker-open.htm), but when I use the syntax for the event handler functions found in the example array on that page, I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: [OneDriveSDK Error] function was missing and not optional

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function od_success( files ) {
            console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Success!' );
        }

        function od_error(e) {
            console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Failed!' );
        }

        function od_cancel() {
            console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Cancelled!' );
        }

        function launchOneDrivePicker() {
            var odOptions = {
                clientId: <?php echo '"' . esc_attr( get_option( 'rod_api_key' ) ) . '"'; ?>,
                action: "query",
                openInNewWindow: false,
                oneDriveFilePickerSuccess: function(files) { od_success(files) },
                oneDriveFilePickerCancel: function() { od_cancel() },
                oneDriveFilePickerError: function(e) { od_error(e) }
            };

            OneDrive.open( odOptions );
        }

        </script>
```

(Note: This all happens in the context of a WordPress page and is being spat out in the head, while the SDK is enqueued in the footer.)

I have tried just calling the named functions, like so:

```
oneDriveFilePickerSuccess: od_success(files),
oneDriveFilePickerCancel: od_cancel,
oneDriveFilePickerError: od_error(e)
```

This only works without passing params (e.g., `od_success()`), but in that event, it calls all three in sequence and then gives the error above. If I add params to the call as above, it tells me `files` is undefined.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: could you provide the exact error message?

Comment: Thanks Simon, I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in documentation :

> Note: If openInNewWindow is false, then all callback functions must be declared globally on the page before the SDK is referenced to guarantee the functions will be called. When registered globally the callback function names are renamed with a prefix of oneDriveFilePicker. For example, success becomes oneDriveFilePickerSuccess.

You must define option like :

```
var oneDriveFilePickerError = 
function () {
  console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Failed!' );
}

var oneDriveFilePickerSuccess = 
function ( files ) {
  console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Success!' );
}

var oneDriveFilePickerCancel =
function ( e ) {
  console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Cancelled!' );
}

function launchOneDrivePicker() {
   var odOptions = {
      clientId: '...',
      action: "query",
      openInNewWindow: false,
      success: 'oneDriveFilePickerSuccess',
      cancel: 'oneDriveFilePickerCancel',
      error: 'oneDriveFilePickerError'
   };

   OneDrive.open( odOptions );
 }
 launchOneDrivePicker()
```

See this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/ZMtF5IAgp7Vycff6mcaD?p=preview

Comment: This did lead to the functions being called, however, I needed to call the cbs like so, `success()`, `cancel()`, `error()`. I also couldn't pass any params through the call: `success(files)` throws the `files is undefined` error. Finally, doing this called all three functions in succession followed by the error, `[OneDriveSDK Error] function was missing and not optional`, as though it was just calling all callbacks ad infinitum.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand. You have another error with my answer ?
If you want to call success() you can apply on oneDriveFilePickerSuccess your last setting : 

oneDriveFilePickerSuccess: function(files) { success(files) }

Comment: I do @Silvinius, I get the following with the code you gave me above: `Uncaught Error: [OneDriveSDK Error] function was missing and not optional` -- seems like it won't take anon functions and the param doesn't pass with a named function

Comment: There is another way you can pass by string. I edited my post

Comment: Unfortunately, I get exactly the same error: `Uncaught Error: [OneDriveSDK Error] function was missing and not optional`

Comment: Oh no, found it-- the CB prefix was in your first edit but not your second and it appears to work without the prefix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

your functions are anonymous functions, in order to make them global functions in this sense you have to:

```
function oneDriveFilePickerSuccess( files ) {
    console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Success!' );
}

function oneDriveFilePickerError() {
    console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Failed!' );
}

function oneDriveFilePickerCancel( e ) {
    console.log( 'OneDrive Launch Cancelled!' );
}

function launchOneDrivePicker() {
    var odOptions = {
        clientId: <?php echo '"' . esc_attr( get_option( 'rod_api_key' ) ) . '"'; ?>,
        action: "query",
        openInNewWindow: false,
        success: 'oneDriveFilePickerSuccess',
        cancel: 'oneDriveFilePickerCancel',
        error: 'oneDriveFilePickerError'
    };

   OneDrive.open( odOptions );
}
```

It is important to reference the functions by their names, instead of wrapping them into anonymous functions or hand over references to them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I included the referenced JS in the head and OneDrive.js in the footer. I tried the functions inside and out of the anon functions, but it didn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Do you include the `OneDrive.js` script before or after this snippet? I think what they mean by "declared globally before referencing the SDK" is that you first declare your callback functions and then include their SDK script, so the SDK can register these functions (that's why it is important to name these functions correctly). That would mean you would have to split your code like

```
<script>
    function oneDriveFilePickerSuccess(files) {
        console.log('OneDrive Launch Success!');
    }

    function oneDriveFilePickerError() {
        console.log('OneDrive Launch Failed!');
    }

    function oneDriveFilePickerCancel(e) {
        console.log('OneDrive Launch Cancelled!');
    }
</script>

<script src="https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js"></script>

<script>
    function launchOneDrivePicker() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

In one script the position of a function declaration doesn't matter, but each script tag is executed on its own, so it does matter then.

Comment: After moving the launch function def below the SDK, still getting the same error. I'm going to clarify in my post.